# ASP.Net MVC3 Rendering Database stored images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a controller as follows that returns a byte[]

```
public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Show(int id)
        {


            var proxy = new ServiceProxy();
            var imgData = proxy.GetCheckImage(id);
            return File(imgData, "image/tiff");
           }
    }
```

My view is as follows:

```
<img alt ="" src='@Url.Action("show", "image", new { id = 36 })'/>
```

I have hard coded the image id for debug purposes.

On the browser in chrome/ie I get a x where the image needs to be displayed. But if I go directly to the controller url http://localhost/website/image/show/id=36, the image gets downloaded fine to the local machine.I have tried creating a separate ActionResult in the same controller which is used to display other data without any luck. This is a Win7/IIS7 local dev. environment.

Comment: Thanks Sam/Smartcaveman. I was successful in rendering the jpeg version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Tiff supported by Chrome/IE? I don't think it is...

Answer (score 3):

Tiff is not supported by most browsers.  The solution is to convert the Tiff to a Png file.

This post has the solution to your problem:

[Render image to the screen from MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172380/render-image-to-the-screen-from-mvc-controller/5172621#5172621)