# ASP.NET MVC: Render view as image

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, render

I have a partial view in my web application that renders a "widget" with several fields. Besides displaying the widget in the site I am sending it through email, and this works for some of the email clients, but some don't understand the inline CSS correctly.

I was thinking on rendering the partial view on the server and creating a single image from it, then embeding the image in the email, this way everyone will see the widget in the same way.

Is there a way to render a partial view on the server side and create an image from it? If so, where can I get more info about it? I've googled it and I don't seem to find any relevant information.

Thanks

Comment: A bit old, but relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image

Comment: Also relevant: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx.  I don't know if ASP.NET MVC 3 now has something like this built in natively.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172380

Comment: Actually that's not what I'm looking for, I'm trying to create an image of my html/css/images, basically a screenshot of my partial view.

Comment: In that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image

Comment: How often is the widget updated?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, that's close, I was thinking on a .NET library that could do that, I guess I'll research those standalone apps to see if they can be used in my hosting server.

Comment: @UchenduNwachuku The widget is completely dynamic, i.e. It represents a user of the system, something like the box with the information about the user here in SO (picture, username, points, badges, etc)

Comment: @willvv In that case, I doubt there is any viable way to do what you are asking in the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: @willvv Instead, I think you need to investigate rendering the widget using the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace to create an image of the widget on the server side.