# How to display image from JSON in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, image, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to display an image from my database. I post a form with some data with Json. After that, I get the result from the database. It's almost the same as a reaction in facebook. You post your comment and you will get your comment formatted and your profileimage on the side.

I managed to get the data back but I don't know how to get the image on the screen...
Should I try to create and url? I tryed that but I don't know how to resolve the url in a javascript file.

Sorry, i'm new with Json and MVC 3.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display image from database in asp mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc)

Comment: I tryed this but i need to render some html tags (some table rows and cols) with an image in JavaScript. Now I dont know how to make the good url in JavaScript. The url must be relative so you can use it in any page you like...

Comment: Just use Url.Action() to generate an url to the action that returns your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit stupid... I forgot that you could just use the controller and then the action. I did ImageController and not Image so the action wasn't found. Thats why I thought that this wouldn't worked. I now make an url property on the server and send that with Json. That property is rendered in the src attribute of the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

HttpHandler works well in displaying images either in image control or in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not efficient at all for sending/receiving binary data like images. I would use FileResult. This reference will help you.

[Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand how to get a picture back on the screen. The thing is that I dont know how to render a good url. Say i have an imagecontroller with action getimage with profileid as parameter. Now i have the id in my json result in my JavaScript file. How do I render the proper url??

Comment: Normally you would use @url.Action or something like that. But now you are in a JavaScript file so you cant use it

Comment: I am not sure I understood you well. Let's say your route is {controller}/{action}/{id} and profileid is 3. Then url of image must be, for example, "/Image/GetImage/3" . So everything is fixed except for id part. Why is this a problem in javascript?

Comment: If the image is created on the fly and not stored in Hard Disk or DB, how should it be rendered from JSON result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Do you actually wish to retrieve the image in the JSON data request? I would simply return the URL for the image on your web-server and dynamically insert a 'img' with "src=URL-FROM-JSON" into your webpage via Javascript. There are a lot of functions in the JQuery library to help with this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand how to get a picture back on the screen. The thing is that I dont know how to render a good url. Say i have an imagecontroller with action getimage with profileid as parameter. Now i have the id in my json result in my JavaScript file. How do I render the proper url??

Comment: Normally you would use @url.Action or something like that. But now you are in a JavaScript file so you cant use it

Comment: For a given profileId you would have to have the associated files somewhere on the web server with an absolute path, so I'm not sure what you mean by generating a good URL?

For example, it seems that facebook puts all profile pictures under the static link https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/profilePictureID