# Show an image from the database with asp.net MVC is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried to implement this solution here:
[Display image from database in asp mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc)

But the picture is not showing.   I wonder what I could be doing wrong.
ApplicantPosition is a table with a 2 column primary key, that's why I use 2 parameters.
It seems to be pretty simple and I got not compiler errors.

```
public ActionResult Show(int applicantId, int positionId)
    {
        var imageData = unitOfWork.ApplicantPositionRepository.Find(d => d.ApplicantID == applicantId && d.PositionID == positionId).ToList()[0].Applicant.photo;
        return File(imageData, "image/jpg");
    }



<img src="@Url.Action("show", "image", new { applicantId = ViewData["applicantId"] , positionId=ViewData["positionId"]} )"  />
```

This is the initializer of the database that shows that I am loading the pictures.

```
  protected override void Seed(HRContext context)
        {
            #region Status
            Status applied = new Status() { status = "Applied" };
            Status reviewedByHR = new Status() { status = "Reviewed By HR" };
            Status approvedByHR = new Status() { status = "Approved by HR" };
            Status rejectedByHR = new Status() { status = "Rejected by HR" };
            Status assignedToTechnicalDepartment = new Status() { status = "Assigned to Technical Department" };
            Status approvedByTechnicalDepartment = new Status() { status = "Approved by Technical Department" };
            Status rejectedByTechnicalDepartment = new Status() { status = "Rejected by Technical Department" };

            Status assignedToGeneralManager = new Status() { status = "Assigned to General Manager" };
            Status approvedByGeneralManager = new Status() { status = "Approved by General Manager" };
            Status rejectedByGeneralManager = new Status() { status = "Rejected by General Manager" };

            context.Status.Add(applied);
            context.Status.Add(reviewedByHR);
            context.Status.Add(approvedByHR);
            context.Status.Add(rejectedByHR);
            context.Status.Add(assignedToTechnicalDepartment);
            context.Status.Add(approvedByTechnicalDepartment);
            context.Status.Add(rejectedByTechnicalDepartment);
            context.Status.Add(assignedToGeneralManager);
            context.Status.Add(approvedByGeneralManager);
            context.Status.Add(rejectedByGeneralManager); 
            #endregion    

            #region Position
            Position netdeveloper = new Position() { name = ".net developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };
            Position javadeveloper = new Position() { name = "java developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };
            context.Positions.Add(netdeveloper);
            context.Positions.Add(javadeveloper); 
            #endregion

            #region Applicants
            Applicant luis = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "Luis",
                skypeuser = "le.valencia",
                telephone = "0491732825",
                photo = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\LUIS.SIMBIOS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SlnHR\HRRazorForms\Content\pictures\1.jpg")
            };

            Applicant john = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "John",
                skypeuser = "jo.valencia",
                telephone = "3435343543",
                photo = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\LUIS.SIMBIOS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SlnHR\HRRazorForms\Content\pictures\2.jpg")
            };

            context.Applicants.Add(luis);
            context.Applicants.Add(john); 
            #endregion

            #region ApplicantsPositions
            ApplicantPosition appicantposition = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant = luis,
                Position = netdeveloper,
                appliedDate = DateTime.Today,
                Status = applied
            };

            ApplicantPosition appicantposition2 = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant = john,
                Position = javadeveloper,
                appliedDate = DateTime.Today,
                Status = applied
            };        

            context.ApplicantsPositions.Add(appicantposition);            
            context.ApplicantsPositions.Add(appicantposition2); 
            #endregion

            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: what type of database initializer are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an incorrect syntax, try this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Show", new { applicantId = item.ApplicantID, positionId=item.PositionID  })" />
```