# 'System.IO.File' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to use this answer from an old post:
[Display image from database in asp mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc)
which is:

```
public class ImageController
{
    public ActionResult Show( int id )
    {
        var imageData = ...get bytes from database...

        return File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the following error:

'System.IO.File' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

This is what I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the method is returning `ActionResult` in the method signature but your method returns a `File`?

Comment: This was the answer in the post (I added a link to it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your `ImageController` derives from [`Controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx) which is where the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208.aspx) method is defined:

```
public class ImageController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Show( int id )
    {
        var imageData = ...get bytes from database...
        return File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `using System.IO` if not required. otherwise you may use

```
return base.File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
```

**OR**

```
return System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
```