# Images displayed through Hyperlink on an MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image-processing

I have an MVC3 application that has a view with a table and  links to click on to display the image.  Client did not want the image to display directly in grid due to size.

I have the images stored in a SQL Server db.  Every example I've seen to retrieve the byte[] from the db and display it involves saving to a file first.  Is there a way to do this with a Memory Stream to Response.Write it directly and bypass the file i/o?

Comment: I also tried converting the byte[] to base64string and passing it on url.action, but it's giving me the URI action was too long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this answer [Display image from database in asp mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc)

Instead of using the image

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action( "show", "image", new { id = ViewData["imageID"] } ) %>' />
```

use and action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Image", "Action", "Controller", new { id = ViewData["imageID"] } )
```

Just replace ViewData["imageID"]  with the id of the image