# How to get HomeController to call ImageController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

First and foremost I am new to MVC, so I have a learning curve.

After reading the following post - [Display image from database in asp mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc)

I have included in the `_Layout.cshtml` the following markup and razor per the post above

`<img src="@Url.Action("show", "image", new { imageName = Session["WebSite.LogoFileName"]})" />`

The shared view _Layout.cshtml is calling the HomeController which has

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

From what I understand in the post I included the following in the HomeController as well.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Show()
{
    return View();
}
```

The image controller has the following

```
// GET: /Image/
public ActionResult Show(string imageName)
{
    var imageData = ReadBytesFromDatabase(Session["WebSite.LogoFileName"].ToString());

    return File(imageData, "image/jpg");  //I have excluded the File method on purpose.
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `ImageController` from `HomeController`? This syntax will call `Show` method from `ImageController`: `<img src="@Url.Action("show", "image", new { imageName = Session["WebSite.LogoFileName"]})" />`

Comment: I feel your pain, MVC is a difficult learning curve.

Comment: Ok, so why is the ImageController not being called?  Again, please understand the learning level...

Comment: I think you need to explain what your purpose is, are you trying to get the imageData? or something else?

Comment: I am streaming Images from a MemoryStream by passing the imageName to the Controller...   The File(imageData, "image/jpg") is a helper method that will ReadBytesFromDatabase from a SQL Server FileStream by passing the LogoFileName.

Comment: You can try to put a break point inside the `Show` method in `ImageController` and then run your website. When you load the home page, the break point will be hit. That's when the `Show` method is actually called.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not hitting the break point.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the view you're opening use `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Yes it does use layouts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61994/discussion-between-ekad-and-moojjoo).

Comment: The issue was there is authentication on the site and the attibute of [AllowAnonymous] was not on the controller so it was not getting hit.

Comment: I see, so is the problem solved by adding `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in the `Show` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mistaken Url.Action For Html.Action.

Url.Action creates the link to the action. So in this case it will generate something like:

```
/Images/Show/ImageName.png
```

But you want the result of the action. So Changing Url.Action to Html.Action should do the trick.

Comment: Url.Action("Show"), "Image", new { imageName = Session["WebSite.LogoFileName"]}" is correct and working.  Thank you.