# How to get image by giving the path stored in sql db?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

In this action method I am getting the path of image from the sql database

```
public ActionResult image(int id)
{
     dbCRMEntities dbx = new dbCRMEntities();
     var img = dbx.CONTACTS.FirstOrDefault(Id => id == Id.CONTACT_ID);
     return View(img);
}
```

In view,getting the path of image of image

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.IMAGE)" alt="Image" />
```

but it is only showing the text of alt, how can I render the image.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc

Comment: You probably have an absolute path of the file in your db. You need a relative path (~/ProfileImages/user115.png) to use the @Url.Content method

Comment: Rohit Gupta, this link discussing about image in byte array, my image is stored in local database

Comment: show your `Model` please, spicificaly - `Model.IMAGE` `Type`.

Comment: Check this example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-Image-from-Database-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

In your Controller

```
public ActionResult image(int id)
{
     dbCRMEntities dbx = new dbCRMEntities();
     String img = dbx.CONTACTS.FirstOrDefault(Id => id == Id.CONTACT_ID);
     return base.File(img, "image/jpg");
}
```

In your View

```
<img src="@Url.Action("image","ControllerName")" />
```

Make sure that your path is correct